# how to display data on View after fetching from Json in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a json Output from fetch method, which is something like in this format

```
{ 
"example": {
"id": "301",
"example_n": "example",
"exampleid": "12",
"thumbnail": "some url",

"examplearry": [
  {
    "example_id": "9",
    "exampletitle": "exampletitle ",

  },
  {
    "example_id": "10",
    "exampletitle": "exampletitle",

  },
  {
    "example_id": "7",
    "exampletitle": "exampletitle",


  }, "example_api": "6vvdncv99hbnbscm" 
}
```

Now i want to access example_id and exampletitle. How to use it in react native?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how to do it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html).

Implement something like the fetchData method they have:

```
fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          examplearry: responseData.examplearry,
        });
    })
    .done();
}
```

This will process your json response and then, with this.setState, you can make your data available. After this, just access the examplearry like you would in javascript/react. The tutorial also shows how to do this in detail in the next step.

Comment: yes i was able to do this thing ,but when i started usind data like examplearry.example_n  , examplearry.examplearry.example_id.It is giving undefined.How to use this data to display on views

Comment: Are you sure you're serializing correctly all the data when creating the JSON? Can you show me how your responseData looks like?